# monitor colour profile not loading on startup

Tags: 15.04, icc

I have a monitor device profile set under the Ubuntu system settings, but it does not seem to get loaded when I log in. I have to manually open the settings and click on it again to actually have it load (the radio button is already showing as selected on startup, it just has not applied the profile for some reason until I click it)

Used to work in earlier Ubuntu releases, something changed in the new one I think.

Any fixes?

output from

```
craig@angel:~$ colormgr get-devices
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_HL3170CDW
Owner:         root
Created:       July 12 2015, 07:40:19 PM
Modified:      July 12 2015, 07:40:19 PM
Type:          printer
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         Brother HL-3170CDW series
Vendor:        Brother
Serial:        dnssd://Brother%20HL-3170CDW%20series._ipp._tcp.local/
Format:        ColorSpace.MediaType.Resolution
Scope:         temp
Colourspace:   rgb
Device ID:     cups-HL3170CDW
Profile 1:     HL3170CDW-RGB..
Profile 2:     HL3170CDW-Gray..
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l 

Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Hewlett_Packard_HP_LP2475w_CZC90202JY_craig_1000
Owner:         craig
Created:       July 12 2015, 08:42:21 PM
Modified:      July 12 2015, 08:42:21 PM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         HP LP2475w
Vendor:        Hewlett Packard
Serial:        CZC90202JY
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colourspace:   rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-Hewlett Packard-HP LP2475w-CZC90202JY
Profile 1:     icc-6cfa0490a7da6c20ba74434962bf8584
               /var/lib/colord/icc/LP2475w_coloreyes.icm
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=DP-1
Metadata:      OutputPriority=primary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=c347b2738d6deafedc488db8d4daa385
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `colormgr get-devices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not really a fix, but I found that the problem was the nvidia-settings app (NVIDIA X Server Settings) was resetting/unloading the colour profile when it started up. I have removed (unticked) this entry from Startup Applications and now the colour profile stays applied on login.